# Bluetooth Mouse wheel stopping scrolling after a while but works fine after reconnect

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have `microsoft arc mouse` that works on bluetooth only - it does not have any adapter on  USB port.

I work on

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
```

KDE graphics.

The mouse works perfectly fine but after a while i have to remove it from bluetooth and connect it again to make the scrolling behaviour work again.

Comment: Might be really stupid, but did you already check the batteries?

Comment: @ClaudioKuenzler Yes, the mouse uses red light where batteries has low energy.
And as i posted, when i reconnect the mouse scroll works fine, what's more the mouse click always works fine, so it's only about scroll.

Comment: I've had similar issues on a bluetooth keyboard with "lagging" keys - turned out to be almost empty batteries but keyboard did not show any signs. Hence my hint.
Just for the sake of it, try completely new batteries, too.
Besides that, try the same with a USB wheel-mouse. Do you experience the same? If yes, that would (probably) hint to KDE. If not, maybe the chosen bluetooth driver is not 100% compatible with your mouse?